# What units are commonly used in the UK for body weight and height?

Tags: british-english

I'm creating a form on a website where users enter their body weight and height. The form is intended only for the UK users.

I was trying to find some information what units are commonly used nowadays in the UK but didn't found anything specific.

[Wikiepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrication_in_the_United_Kingdom) says "Imperial units are also often used to describe body measurements", [NHS](https://www.nhs.uk/livewell/loseweight/pages/height-weight-chart.aspx) have their charts in metric units, and [UKMA](https://ukma.org.uk/practical-help/body-and-health/peoples-height-and-weight/) recommends metric units as well.

Q1. If you live in the UK for example in London and someone asked you how tall are you, would you respond in metric units or imperial?

Q2. Does the same apply in the internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If somebody asked me, in conversation, my height and weight (and I felt inclined to answer) I would say "I am five feet ten and half inches tall and I weigh twelve stone". If I had to provide the information on a paper or web form and the only option was metric, I would have to use a calculator or Google to find the correct answers, which I would probably forget until the next time I needed them.  I am a middle aged person born in the UK and have lived there all of my life. There are many UK citizens and residents who would answer using the metric system. The UK is a very culturally diverse society. You should offer both methods.